# Is it possible to accelerate a proton moving in the same direction as the Lorentz force acting upon it?

Tags: electromagnetism

In other words, can the Lorentz force increase the speed of a moving proton if the proton is forced to move in a plane with the same direction as the Lorentz force?

Comment: This is an unusual question. Are you asking about Newton's second law? That law gives the clear answer: "yes".

Comment: @Allure I'm rather asking whether it is possible to force the protons into a trayectory parallel to the lorentz force, to make this force increase their speed, or will the force vector be continously changing to a plane perpendicular to the velocity vector

Comment: Are you sure that's what you're asking? The [Lorentz force](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lorentz_force) has two components, one of which (the electric force) will always move the proton in the same direction.

Comment: @Allure yes, alright so it will be the velocity vector the one that will always stay perpendicular to the lorentz force vector not matter how hard I try to place it parallel to it

Answer (score 1):

You've asked a couple of questions about the Lorentz force.  This is just an equation that summarizes the force on a charge due to the electric and magnetic fields that appear in our reference frame.

It can be more useful to look at these fields and effects separately rather than refer to a single "Lorentz force".

If we have a constant magnetic field, then the force on the particle is always perpendicular to the direction of motion.  This means that the speed is never changed *by the the interaction with the magnetic field*.

If we have a constant electric field, then the force on the particle is always in one direction.  If the particle is moving in that direction, then it gains energy from the field and may accelerate.

Therefore a constant magnetic field cannot change the speed of a proton, but a constant electric field can.